# URL is changing, output - not! (django)

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm new to django, so  quetions may be a bit stupid...
I've deploy my project on VDS with nginx+fastcgi. On dev server everything was OK, but on VDS every URL outputs the main page (pattern '^$'), even those, which not described in urls.py and may out 404. What is the problem?

Comment: Please share your urls.py code so we can see what's going on. A 200 message means okay.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, see nginx's access.log to see webserver is receiving requests correctly.

Comment: I'm a very newbie :) So I didn't really understand if webserver receiving requests correctly. For example, thats line:
109.86.181.200 - - [28/Feb/2010:10:58:20 +0300] "GET /equipment/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2251 "http://88.198.29.111/prototyping/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.307.11 Safari/532.9"
Is everything OK?